# Why does my window keep flashing in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I made a window in pygame, tried to make the window white and even though I only call pygame.display.update() once it keeps flashing between white and black.

This is my code:

```
import pygame

running = True
pygame.init()

White = (255, 255, 255)

while running == True:
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1400, 800))
    screen.fill(White)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
```

I tried changing it to pygame.display.flip() but it still stayed the same.
I also tried to put pygame.display.update() out of the loop but then the screen just stayed black.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the Pygame window (`pygame.display.set_mode`) once before the application loop instead of constantly creating a new window in the application loop:

```py
import pygame

running = True
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1400, 800))
White = (255, 255, 255)

while running == True:
    screen.fill(White)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
```